# Subprocess not ending

Tags: python, subprocess

I am attempting to create a launcher for a python game, and am encountering an issue. When the code in my subprocess ends, the main thread doesn't resume.

Here is the thread that calls the subprocess

```
class ClientThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, port, host, name, colour):
        super(ClientThread, self).__init__()
        self.port = port
        self.host = host
        self.name = name
        self.colour = colour
        self.running = False
        self.toKill = False

    def run(self):
        self.running = True
        print("Started")
        args = self.host+" "+str(self.port)+" "+self.name.replace(" ", "_")+" "+str(self.colour[0])+" "+str(self.colour[1])+" "+str(self.colour[2])
        subprocess.call("C:\Python33\python.exe Client.py "+args)
        print("DONE CLIENT")
        self.toKill = True
```

Here is the code at the end of the subprocess

```
print("NOTHING")
sock.close()
print("Socket")
try:
    gc.join(0.5)
    print("Threads")
except:
    print("ERROR")
pygame.quit()
print("Pygame")
exit(0)
```

Here is the console output:

```
ESCAPE
Connected Status
NOTHING
Socket
Threads
Pygame
```

At the end, it should say "Client done" when the thread resumes. I just want `toKill` to become true when the process ends any system works. I am utterly confused by this and can't find any help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think the `SystemExit` exception from `exit(0)` is being re-raised inside the parent, causing it to terminate prematurely

Comment: Even without that line, the thread still fails to resume

Comment: It should print 'DONE CLIENT'. Can you show a [minimal, complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) please?

Comment: you might need all the code to reproduce it, it's all on github: https://github.com/Aree-Vanier/aree-vanier.github.io/tree/master/python. when you launch, enter a 3 digit number in the hue box and press launch server. Once it's running, press escape to quit. The client closes, but it doesn't print client done. If you run the launcher in its own folder, the files will all download there on run.

Comment: I don't think that's all needed to reproduce the problem. The idea of a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is to reduce the code so it is more likely that someone finds the problem. Maybe you even find it yourself while reducing the amount of unrelated code.

Comment: After switching to IDLE (from Eclipse) I noticed that the command windiw launched by the proscess doesnt close at the end, so there is likely a hangig thread of some sort in the client.py file. I cant find anything, and I don't expect you to read all of my code, so i'll just have to do more digging to find it. Thanks for trying to help.